# On clicking first radio button, automatically open radio button inside of that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have list of packages. All of them are radio buttons. When clicked, i get list of price options who are also radio button, but only first price option, others are normal buttons.

When i click on package radio button, i need first price option also checked and active, so it can show some values inside of it. Others needs to be closed.

```
<div class="col-md-12 packageList">

         <h4 class="col-sm-4"><input class="col-sm-1" id="id_radio26"
         type="radio" value="26" name="radio"> Paket 1</h4>

         <h4 class="col-sm-3">Credits:<span> 20</span></h4>
         <h4 class="col-sm-3">Duration: <span>2min</span></h4>
                                <h4 class="col-sm-2"><span>$200</span>/Month</h4>

                            </div>


                            <br>

                            <div class="package" id="package26">
                          <label>Price Option:&nbsp; </label>86&nbsp;&nbsp;

                                        <label class="hideRadio">
                                            <input class="price_option" type="radio"
                                                   value="86"
                                                   name="price_option" checked="checked">

                                        </label>


                                    <br>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 valuesInput">
                                        <div class="" id="price_option_div_86">
                                            <div class="col-md-4 valuesTable">
                                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    <tr class="bg-primary content-box-header">
                                                        <th>Values</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </thead>


                                                        <tbody>
                                                        <th>
                                                            Vrednost 31<br>
                                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                                   name="value-86[]"
                                                                   value="Vrednost 31">
                                                        </th>
                                                        </tbody>


                                                        <tbody>
                                                        <th>
                                                            Vrednost 32<br>
                                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                                   name="value-86[]"
                                                                   value="Vrednost 32">
                                                        </th>
                                                        </tbody>


                                                </table>
                                            </div>


                                                                                        </div>
                                    </div>



                                        <label class="hideRadio">

                                            <button class="price_option" type="button"
                                                    name="price_option" value="91">
                                                Alternative Payment
                                            </button>

                                        </label>


                                    <br>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 valuesInput">
                                        <div class="" id="price_option_div_91">
                                            <div class="col-md-4 valuesTable">
                                                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                                                    <thead>
                                                    <tr class="bg-primary content-box-header">
                                                        <th>Values</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    </thead>


                                                        <tbody>
                                                        <th>
                                                            assd<br>
                                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                                   name="value-91[]"
                                                                   value="assd">
                                                        </th>
                                                        </tbody>


                                                        <tbody>
                                                        <th>
                                                            asdasd<br>
                                                            <input type="hidden"
                                                                   name="value-91[]"
                                                                   value="asdasd">
                                                        </th>
                                                        </tbody>


                                                </table>
                                            </div>


                                                                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                            </div>
```

This is my script for now:

```
        /*Radio buttons */
    $('div[id^="package"]').hide();

    $('body').on('click', 'input[id^="id_radio"]', function () {
        $('div[id^="package"]').hide();
        $('#package' + $(this).val()).show();
        console.log($(this).val());

    });

    $('div[id^="price_option_div"]').hide();


    $('body').on('click', '.price_option', function () {
        $('div[id^="price_option_div_"]').hide();
        $("#price_option_div_" + $(this).val()).show();
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that u cant change your HTML Code and add some Classes. Therefore you could use something like this:

```js
/* Radio buttons */

    // set variables
    var $packages = $('div[id^="package"]'),
        $priceOptions = $('div[id^="price_option_div"]'),
        priceOptionNr;

    // hide stuff
    $packages.hide();
    $priceOptions.hide();

    $('input[id^="id_radio"]').on('click', function () {
        // hide stuff
        $packages.hide();
        $priceOptions.hide();
      
        // safe price option value
        priceOptionNr = $('#package' + $(this).val())
            .find('.price_option').val();
      
        // show specific price option + connected div 
        $('#package' + $(this).val()).show()
          .find('#price_option_div_' + priceOptionNr).show();
    });

    $('.price_option').on('click', function () {
        $priceOptions.hide();
        $("#price_option_div_" + $(this).val()).show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 packageList">
    <h4 class="col-sm-4"><input class="col-sm-1" id="id_radio26" type="radio" value="26" name="radio"> Paket 1</h4>
    <h4 class="col-sm-3">Credits:<span> 20</span></h4>
    <h4 class="col-sm-3">Duration: <span>2min</span></h4>
    <h4 class="col-sm-2"><span>$200</span>/Month</h4>
</div> <br>

<div class="package" id="package26">
    <label>Price Option:&nbsp; </label>86&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label class="hideRadio"> <input class="price_option" type="radio" value="86" name="price_option" checked="checked"> </label> <br>

    <div class="col-md-12 valuesInput">
        <div class="" id="price_option_div_86">
            <div class="col-md-4 valuesTable">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-primary content-box-header"> <th>Values</th> </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <th> Vrednost 31<br> <input type="hidden" name="value-86[]" value="Vrednost 31"></th>
                    </tbody>
                    <tbody>
                        <th> Vrednost 32<br> <input type="hidden" name="value-86[]" value="Vrednost 32"></th>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <label class="hideRadio"> <button class="price_option" type="button" name="price_option" value="91"> Alternative Payment</button> </label>  <br>

    <div class="col-md-12 valuesInput">
        <div class="" id="price_option_div_91">
            <div class="col-md-4 valuesTable">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="bg-primary content-box-header">
                            <th>Values</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <th> assd<br> <input type="hidden" name="value-91[]" value="assd"></th>
                    </tbody>
                    <tbody>
                        <th> asdasd<br> <input type="hidden" name="value-91[]" value="asdasd"></th>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, this partially worked. But now, Alternative Payment button doesn't do anything, and it should be clickable and showing its own values when clicked

Comment: Oh yeah forgot about that last event. Edited the post. Now it should work properly. Its now possible to just toggle between the two payment methods by clicking the button or the radio.